# CKeditor not rendering with Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, ckeditor

The ckeditor was functioning well in the last version of meteor but the day I updated the meteor version, the ckeditor is not functioning. In its place, a textarea is appearing.
The error displayed in the console is:-
**TypeError: $(...).ckeditor is not a function**

HTML code

```
<template name="addPoems">
    <form>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
        <li><textarea name="poem" placeholder="Poem" id="basketSpace"></textarea></li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="Add poem"></li>
    </ul>
    </form>
</template>
```

Client Code

```
  Template.addPoems.onRendered(function(){
    $('#basketSpace').ckeditor(function(){
      $('.cke').css({'border':'2px solid silver'});
    });
  });
```

One thing to note is that this code was working fine in the last version of meteor. Can anybody help me regarding this? 
Apologies for any mistake in posting the question.

Comment: we need some info on how you initialize it it says it can't find the `ckeditor`

Comment: Sorry if I am making a very basic mistake but i have used it in the previous version of meteor and it was working fine

Comment: @MarkUretsky I have used these in the html file
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: well I'm not sure in what file or if it's rendered correctly, The problem is loading order you can try and use this package for ckeditor it probably have correct load order and your code will work fine https://atmospherejs.com/lsun/ckeditor p.s I will upad the answer with even better solution for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `CKEDITOR.replace('EDITOR ID');` here is a working demo: https://meteorpad.com/pad/sxn5LTRTNzSHZS2Wh/Leaderboard

it happens because there is no jQuery adapter on your ckeditor or maybe its included in the full featured ckeditor only you can use the direct method to initialize the ckeditor and it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you for helping me till now but still I have not been able to solve the problem. This error is still being given:-**Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ckeditor is not a function**. I tried to solve using the "kadira:dochead" package. This is the code within the html head tags  '<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>'. Do I need to do anything in the public folder. I do not know from where the error is coming.

Comment: Please help. I have not been able to solve it on my own.

Comment: @SujoyDe use `CKEDITOR.replace('EDITOR ID');` here is a working demo: http://meteorpad.com/pad/sxn5LTRTNzSHZS2Wh/Leaderboard it happens because its a problem there is no jQuery adapter on your ckeditor or maybe its included in the full featured ckeditor if you need jquery support you can look for ckeditor jquery adapter and find out why its not working for you, or just use the direct method it works fine :)

Comment: Thank you so very much @Mark Uretsky. Can you make this comment an answer, i will accept and upvote the answer. Again thank you so much.